# Unable to set refresh rate to 60Hz on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution

### Update

I recently had to update the NVIDIA drivers for some other reason and the issue seems to have fixed itself in the new version.

### The problem

I am unable to set the refresh rate above 30Hz on my display.

### Specs

- Display: Samsung U32J590UQ ([imgur: Display in NVIDIA Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KTPd.png))
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 ([imgur: GPU in NVIDIA Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBgId.png))
- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS ([imgur: Complete specs in Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJtaX.png))

### Background

#### Screenshots

[imgur: Refresh Rates available on Ubuntu: only 30Hz is available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8BVB.png)

The 60Hz refresh rate only becomes available when I choose some resolution lower than 3840x2160.

[imgur: Resolutions available on Ubuntu: other values refresh rate are available at other resolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R84gN.png)

### Screenshots on Windows

I know my current setup can handle 60Hz because this combination of resolution and refresh rate is available on windows and it works correctly:

[imgur: Refresh Rates available on Windows: 60Hz is available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbNSm.png)

[imgur: Resolutions available on Windows: the same resolution is available and being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT0qP.png)

I didn't change anything in my setup to make this work on windows. I didn't even change any cables or ports.

### Attempted solutions

These are some things I have tried already:

1. disconnecting all other displays,
2. using different ports on the GPU,
3. updating the NVidia driver, and
4. going through all posts over here about refresh rates and trying everything being suggested.

   1. Most answers suggest something like `xrandr --output DP-2 --size 3840x2160 --refresh 60`: the monitor flickers but nothing happens.
   2. Using a DisplayPort cable v1.2. The cable I'm using: [imgur: Displayport V1.2 3M Dp1230 Plusc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WIaQ.jpg). It was listed as "Displayport V1.2 3M Dp1230 Plusc" on amazon. It works at 60Hz on windows with the same cable.

### xrandr output

This is what I have in `xrandr` for this display. I decided to use a lower resolution for now because it bothers me less than the reduced refresh rate:

```
DP-2 connected primary 5120x2880+2732+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 697mm x 392mm
   3840x2160     30.00 +  29.97  
   2560x1440     59.95* 
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
```

Interestingly, I have a 3-year-old 4k Samsung display of the same series (U28E590) and it doesn't have this problem:

```
DP-0 connected 4384x2466+7852+191 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 607mm x 345mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  30.00  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a DisplayPort cable that is version1.2?

I recently purchased a Samsung M70B 43" and had a similar issue.  What worked for me was getting a new DiplayPort 1.2 cable since the specs for my display mentioned that the full 4k resolution was only achievable at 60Hz with v1.2.  The specs on your display say the same: [Samsung U32J590UQ (LU32J590UQNXZA)](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/uhd-and-wqhd/32-uj590-uhd-monitor-lu32j590uqnxza/#specs)

I checked every DP cable I had to no avail.  I ordered a v1.2 from Amz and four hours later, had my M70B display at 60Hz instantly.

Comment: Is there a way to check the cable version through the OS? All I could infer is I bought these cables recently (it said "Displayport V1.2 3M Dp1230 Plusc" on amazon) and I know the monitor is able to work at 60Hz with whatever cable I currently have because it works on windows.

Comment: This is the cable I'm using: [imgur: Displayport V1.2 3M Dp1230 Plusc](https://imgur.com/a/iK26WQU)